# Place Image into two column LaTeX

Tags: graphics, floats, multicol

I have a LaTeX template of journal article (European Alliance for Innovation). Containing two columns. I'm facing an issue while adding image into two column. While, scaling image solve my issue, but problem is that image showing above on the text of second column. How can i solve this issue? bellow is my code.

```
 \begin{figure}
    \centering
    %\includegraphics [scale=0.1]{3D}
    \includegraphics [scale=0.8]{ThesisFigs/myfig/lpyear.png}
    \caption{Yearly Publications on the topic of Link Prediction}
    \label{Fig:2}
 \end{figure}
```

after excuting the above code, this is what i'm getting.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! `\begin{figure*} ...\end{figure*}`, i.e. add `*` after `figure`.

Comment: Thanks, Its working. I already used * with \begin{figure} but forget to add * with \end{figure}